# Compiling C code with -lcrypto but perror() prints "No such file or directory" at runtime

Tags: c, linux, gcc, openssl

I have just noticed this strange error: **No such file or directory** after compiling C code with `-lcrypto` and calling `perror()` at runtime. The code compiles fine and runs with exit code = 0 even when I SH1 hash with the crypto library.

###### Here is a sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main(){

    perror("Test");

    return 0;
}
```

###### Compile command:

`gcc -o test test.c -lcrypto`

I have also tried to compile OpenSSL to my own location and link from there and I still get the same error (*example: -L /usr/local/ssl/* )

I have also tried to look at the [cryptlib.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/cryptlib.c) file for any file being opened. (*I am not sure if I am looking at the right place*)

Please help me understand why is this message and how can I solve it, if possible.

I am using Linux/Fedora

---

###### strace ./trace :

```
execve("./test", ["./test"], 0x7ffed99e5030 /* 46 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x2366000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffce623a7d0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=59656, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 59656, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fda59df5000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\300\7\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=3096376, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fda59df3000
mmap(NULL, 3071784, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fda59b05000
mmap(0x7fda59b7f000, 1761280, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7a000) = 0x7fda59b7f000
mmap(0x7fda59d2d000, 598016, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x228000) = 0x7fda59d2d000
mmap(0x7fda59dbf000, 196608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2b9000) = 0x7fda59dbf000
mmap(0x7fda59def000, 16168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fda59def000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260|\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0 \0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 48, 848) = 48
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0n<\10z\312\2339T\236K\251,E\37\369"..., 68, 896) = 68
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=3228320, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
mmap(NULL, 1892824, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fda59936000
mprotect(0x7fda5995c000, 1679360, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fda5995c000, 1363968, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7fda5995c000
mmap(0x7fda59aa9000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x173000) = 0x7fda59aa9000
mmap(0x7fda59af6000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bf000) = 0x7fda59af6000
mmap(0x7fda59afc000, 33240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fda59afc000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\3605\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=103184, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 102408, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fda5991c000
mprotect(0x7fda5991f000, 86016, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fda5991f000, 57344, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7fda5991f000
mmap(0x7fda5992d000, 24576, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x11000) = 0x7fda5992d000
mmap(0x7fda59934000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7fda59934000
mmap(0x7fda59935000, 8, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fda59935000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=37288, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 24688, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fda59915000
mmap(0x7fda59917000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fda59917000
mmap(0x7fda59919000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7fda59919000
mmap(0x7fda5991a000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7fda5991a000
mmap(0x7fda5991b000, 112, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fda5991b000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\201\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0 \0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 48, 792) = 48
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0{\f\332\370x\253O\231\7\2049\330d\257p\245"..., 68, 840) = 68
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=301592, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 131472, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fda598f4000
mprotect(0x7fda598fb000, 81920, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fda598fb000, 61440, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x7fda598fb000
mmap(0x7fda5990a000, 16384, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7fda5990a000
mmap(0x7fda5990f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1a000) = 0x7fda5990f000
mmap(0x7fda59911000, 12688, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fda59911000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fda598f2000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fda598f3480) = 0
mprotect(0x7fda59af6000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fda5990f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fda5991a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fda59934000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fda59dbf000, 180224, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x403000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fda59e34000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fda59df5000, 59656)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7fda598f3750)         = 56899
set_robust_list(0x7fda598f3760, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7fda598fbbb0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fda59907a00}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7fda598fbc50, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fda59907a00}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "0\n", 2)                       = 2
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/system-fips", F_OK)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x80002 (flags O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x2366000
brk(0x2387000)                          = 0x2387000
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
write(3, "Test: No such file or directory\n", 32Test: No such file or directory
) = 32
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: `perror();` is not valid, this function needs a string argument. Once you add it, the code compiles and runs on my system without an error, regardless of linker flags. If the code starts at all, your linker flags are probably correct and there is some other error at run time (which cannot happen with **this** code).

Comment: When I compile without **-lcrypto** there is no message.

Comment: If your program runs and prints the message, you are linking it correctly. Are you sure you are getting `Test: no such file or directory` printed? This IMHO cannot happen on a correctly configured Linux system. You may want to look at the output of `strace ./test` for clues.

Comment: I am just as confused. I have added the first few lines of `strace` results on the question

Comment: The first few lines are irrelevant. Look at the end. What is the last failed call before `write(2, "Test`...?

Comment: I posted all the results

Comment: Normally you call `perror` only *after* a system call has returned an error.  Any other time, `errno` is unpredictable, and `perror` can easiy give unexpected results.  See [here](http://c-faq.com/stdio/printferrno.html) for a classic example

Comment: The program prints "Test: Success", not "Test: no such file or directory". Closing as not reproducible.

Comment: I'm guessing that when you compile with `-lcrypto`, you get some extra initialization code which checks for some optional init or config file.  (Perhaps the file `/etc/system-fips` mentioned in your strace output.) Absence of that file does not cause an error, but it might leave `ENOENT` sitting in `errno`.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. Sorry, I posted the wrong results

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I get "Test: Success", too (and "Test: Undefined error: 0" on my Mac), but I can easily imagine the OP's system having a different quasi-random value in `errno`.  [Love your username btw.]

Comment: OK you have a FIPS-enabled system (which most people don't) but /etc/system-fips is not present. Perhaps it is configured incorrectly, or this error is benign, I really have no idea. This is not a question of linkling or gcc, this is a question of configuring FIPS.

Comment: Okay, I have been reading up about FIPS. In the meantime I decided to set `errno=0`. Thnx everyone for yr contributions

Comment: it looks like your system is NOT FIPS enabled and the error is benign, sorry, I am not terribly familiar wit it.